# Check existence of Swift Array item with Generic

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, generics, xcode6

I want to create an extension of a Swift Array that returns random N number of elements.

```
extension Array {
  func getRandomItems(max:Int) -> [T] {
    var randomItems = [T]()

    repeat
    {
      let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.count)))
      if contains(randomItems, self[randomNumber]) {
        randomItems.append(self[randomNumber])
      }
    } while (randomItems.count < max)

    return randomItems
  }

}


print(["Canada","Brazil","China","Japan","U.S"].getRandomNumbers(3))
```

Compiler says "Cannot invoke 'contains' with an argument list of type '([T], T)'
How to make this function work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you're only extending Arrays that conform to `Equatable`. Also, in the newest beta, `T` has been replaced with `Element`:

```
extension Array where Element : Equatable {
  func getRandomItems(max:Int) -> [Element] {
    var randomItems = [Element]()

    repeat
    {
      let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.count)))
      if randomItems.contains(self[randomNumber]) {
        randomItems.append(self[randomNumber])
      }
    } while (randomItems.count < max)

    return randomItems
  }

}
```

Your line `if randomItems.contains(self[randomNumber])` should be `if !randomItems.contains(self[randomNumber])`.

Comment: Thank you so much.
I tried this code with Xcode 7.0 beta, but it complains with "Trailing 'where' clause for extension of non-protocol type 'Array'"
Also .contains function call complains "Cannot invoke 'contains' with an argument list of type '(T)'"
Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: You must be on beta 1 or 2, so. The ability to extend Arrays with a where clause is in beta 3. [The new version is here.](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/)